# Call to undefined function _curl()

Tags: php, curl, undefined

[image]

```
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
$url = "https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/new_address?password=$main_password&second_password=$second_password&label=$uid";
if (isset($_POST['amount'])){
    $_SESSION['USD_amount'] = $_POST['amount'];
    $_SESSION['BTC_amount'] = number_format($_SESSION['USD_amount']/$rate, 8, '.', '');
    $temp = _curl($url, '', '');
    $_SESSION['BTC_Address'] = get_string_between($temp, 'address":"', '"');    
}
```

I have curl the latest version installed but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What is a `_curl()` function?

Comment: ...it's a function that curls hair maybe; for bald people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl is initiated with, for example:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
```

there's no function called _curl()

Suggested reading:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: That function actually works in one of my cPanel WebHosting.
But not in an apache server, i have no idea why.